# TYPO3 Special Menu "Browse" - Entry Level

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm stuck in a TS problem related to a special browse HMENU. I'm using TYPO3 7.6.11.

Site Structure:

```
/ Page 1
// Page 1.1
// Page 1.2
// Page 1.3
/ Page 2
/ Page 3
```

I'd like to integrate a Previous / Next navigation for the first navigation level. On Page 1, you can switch to Page 2. On Page 2, you can switch to Page 1 or Page 3. I used following code and it works on the first level:

```
lib.newsletter = COA
lib.newsletter {
    10 = HMENU
    10 {
        special = browse
        special {
            items = prev
        }
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            NO.ATagParams = class="prev"
        }
    }

    20 < .10
    20 {
        special.items = next
        1.NO.ATagParams = class="next"
    }
}
```

When I open a page of the second level, I'd still like to browse on the first level. So when I'm on Page 1.2 and click on the "Next" button, "Page 2" should open.

I've tried to set an entry level in combination with a treeLevel condition but the entryLevel has no effect.

Do you have an idea? Your help is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: There is an extension called gsi_pagenav, which I hope does what you want, unfortunately it is VERY old and I don't know if it works in T3 v6 or v7: https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/gsi_pagenav

Comment: Just had a look, you have to enable basic v6 compatibility, since it is still pibase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`entryLevel` won't work here because it's relative to the current page. You can however set `.special.value` to another page id to make it relative to that page. This property supports `stdWrap` so you can be creative with things like

`.special.value.data = leveluid:1` (page in first level of the root line)

See [TypoScript reference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/DataTypes/Gettext/Index.html#leveltitle-leveluid-levelmedia)

Comment: Works, perfect. Thank you!